# C# Loop through a collection and assign each object to a variable

Tags: list, variables, collections, c#-4.0

I am sure this is quite simple but I cannot seem to get this right.
I have a built up a ICollection of Users. This collection could have 1 or many.
I now want to loop through this collection and assign a variable to each user that I can then use to fill in a spread sheet.

At present I have this code :

```
    string username = null;

        foreach (var user in dailyReport)
        {
             username = user.UserName;
        }

        Cell cell= worksheet.Cells["B5"];
        cell.PutValue(username);
```

Now obviously this just puts the last user  of the collection into cell B5! 
How do I collect all user.UserNames so I can place them in B5, B6, B7 and so on????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the value *inside* the `foreach` loop. The specific thing you are asking for--getting a different variable for every value in the collection--is not possible, and isn't what you want anyway.

```
string column = "B"; // or whatever your column is
int row = 1; // or whatever your starting value is

foreach (var user in dailyReport)
{
    string username = user.UserName;
    string cellAddress = String.Format("{0}{1}", column, row);
    Cell cell = worksheet.Cells[cellAddress];

    cell.PutValue(username);

    row++; // make sure to increment the row, or every username goes in the same cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This worked just as I wanted and you explained it very clearly. Thanks also to @Tony Lukasavage who's answer also worked. Very clean code!

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the user names:

```
List<string> userNames = dailyReport.Select( x=> x.UserName).ToList();
```

Alternatively you can just do the assignment in the loop directly:

```
    int index = 5;
    foreach (var user in dailyReport)
    {
         Cell cell= worksheet.Cells["B"+ index.ToString()];
         cell.PutValue(user.UserName);
         index++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 5;
foreach (var user in dailyReport)
{
    worksheet.Cells["B" + (i++).ToString()].PutValue(user.UserName);
}
```